# Powershell Import-csv bug

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to use import-csv with -erroraction SilentlyContinue but when the file imports it still throws an error:

```
Import-Csv : The member "Id" is already present.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Parse.ps1:65 char:24
+ ...  $csvData = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $file.FullName -ErrorAction Silen ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Csv], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyPresentPSMemberInfoInternalCollectionAdd,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

I've tried setting Erroractionpreference as well but its still throwing the error.

Anyone else seen this or know how to get around it?

Comment: Does your CSV file have two columns/headers with the same name? Since that is a terminating error, you can use try-catch to make it disappear.

Comment: yea I know the root cause.. the next line is IF($error) then I parse the CSV by splitting the first line to a header and renaming duplicates with a number added on. Try/catch worked though, so if you post the comment as a solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your CSV has multiple headers with the same value. The error you are seeing is a terminating error. `-ErrorAction` and `$ErrorActionPreference` do not change the behavior of terminating errors. You can use `try-catch` to respond to a terminating error.

```
try {
    $csvData = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $file.FullName
}
catch {
    # Add response code here
}
```

In some cases, `-ErrorAction` is used to terminate a non-terminating error so that error and exception handling can be done from the perspective of a terminating error.

See [About Preference Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6) for the expected usage of `$ErrorActionPreference` variable and the common parameter `ErrorAction`.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sence. I had no idea terminating errors wouldn't be effected by erroraction stuff. Thanks!!